# Webpack access class from other class

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I'm trying to access class functions from other class which are webpacked.
I have:

```
var App = function () {
    getResponsiveBreakpoint: function(size) {
        var sizes = {
            'xs' : 480,     // extra small
            'sm' : 768,     // small
            'md' : 992,     // medium
            'lg' : 1200     // large
        };

        return sizes[size] ? sizes[size] : 0;
    }
}
```

and I want to access this function from:

```
var Layout = function() {
    var resBreakpointMd = App.getResponsiveBreakpoint('md');
}
```

these classes are webpacked, here's config:

```
    var path                  = require('path'),
        webpack               = require('webpack'),
        ExtractTextPlugin     = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
        autoprefixer          = require('autoprefixer'),
        precss                = require('precss'),
        ProvidePlugin         = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin'),
        jsPath                = './js',
        jsLayoutPath          = './js/layout',
        cssPath               = './css',
        cssLayoutPath         = './css/layout',
        cssThemesPath         = './css/layout/themes';

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            login: [jsPath + '/login.js', cssPath + '/login.css'],
            layout: [jsLayoutPath + '/layout.js', cssLayoutPath + '/layout.css'],
            custom: cssLayoutPath + '/custom.css',
            vendor: [
                cssPath + '/bootstrap.css',
                cssPath + '/bootstrap-switch.css',
                cssPath + '/font-awesome.css',
                cssPath + '/datatables.bootstrap.css',
                cssPath + '/datatables.css',
                cssPath + '/datatables.font-awesome.css',
                cssPath + '/select2.css',
                cssPath + '/select2-bootstrap.css',
                cssPath + '/components.css',
                cssPath + '/plugins.css',
                cssPath + '/daterangepicker.css',
                cssPath + '/uniform.default.css',
                jsPath + '/jquery.js',
                jsPath + '/jquery.blockUI.js',
                jsPath + '/bootstrap.js',
                jsPath + '/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js',
                jsPath + '/bootstrap-switch.js',
                jsPath + '/select2.full.js',
                jsPath + '/jquery.waypoints.min.js',
                jsPath + '/jquery.slimscroll.js',
                jsPath + '/jquery.counterup.js',
                jsPath + '/jquery.uniform.js',
                jsPath + '/jquery.validate.js',
                jsPath + '/jquery.form.js',
                jsPath + '/additional-methods.js',
                jsPath + '/datatables.js',
                jsPath + '/datatables.bootstrap.js',
                jsPath + '/app.js'
            ],
            respond: jsPath + '/respond.src.js',
            excanvas: jsPath + '/excanvas.js'
        },
        output:  {
            path: __dirname + "/../../web/assets/js/", publicPath: '/assets/js/', filename: "[name].js"
        },
        module:  {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-raw-loader!postcss-loader")
                },
                { test: /jquery\.js$/, loader: 'expose?$' },
                { test: /jquery\.js$/, loader: 'expose?jQuery' },
                { test: /datatables\.js$/, loader: 'expose?DataTable' },
                { test: /jquery\.form\.js$/, loader: "imports?define=>false" },
                {
                    test:    /\.js(x)?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader:  'babel',
                    query:   {
                        plugins:   [
                            "transform-class-properties"
                        ],
                        "presets": [
                            "stage-0",
                            "es2015",
                            "react"
                        ],
                        compact: false
                    }
                },
            ],
            postcss: function() {
                return [autoprefixer, precss];
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: "jquery",
                jQuery: "jquery",
                "window.jQuery": "jquery",
                "DataTable": "datatables.net"
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                compress: { warnings: false },
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("commons", "../js/commons.min.js"),
            new ExtractTextPlugin("../css/[name].min.css", {
                allChunks: true
            }),
        ]
    };
```

How can I achieve this? I tried with expose module, but never succeeded. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `import App from './path/to/App'` from within the file containing Layout? If you don't use ES6 (import) you can use `var App = require('./path/to/App/')`

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried adding: var `App = require('./js/app.js');` at top of `layout.js` then I got error layout.js module not found, when I added inside Layout function, I got app.js module not found

Comment: I imagine your path may not be right. It should be relative to layout.js. could it be `var App = require('../app.js');`?

Comment: Now I get `i.getResponsiveBreakpoint is not a function`, and when I `console.log(App)` I get empty object

Comment: yes, you meed to export App from App.js. If you're using ES6 then at the bottom of App.js you can write `export default App`. Looks like you are using ES6 so it's best you use imports and exports.

Comment: Ok this is weird now, I added `export default App` at the end of `App.js`, and imported in `layout.js`, now console.log(App) returns App object, but line below where I called App functions `var resBreakpointMd = App.getResponsiveBreakpoint('md');` I get error `t.getResponsiveBreakpoint is not a function`

Comment: Of course it's not. App is a function. make it an object. `var App = {
    getResponsiveBreakpoint: function(size) {
        var sizes = {
            'xs' : 480,     // extra small
            'sm' : 768,     // small
            'md' : 992,     // medium
            'lg' : 1200     // large
        };

        return sizes[size] ? sizes[size] : 0;
        
}`

Comment: aaah, but I can't make it object, it's quite big function :/

Comment: I moved this down as an answer. let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll rewrite as an answer. There seem to be many things you can do to improve on as part of both JavaScript as Webpack config, but i'll try to focus on the question.

1. Use modules

   ```
   import App from '../app.js';

   var Layout = function() {
       var resBreakpointMd = App.getResponsiveBreakpoint('md');
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   var App = {
       getResponsiveBreakpoint: function(size) {
           var sizes = {
               'xs' : 480,     // extra small
               'sm' : 768,     // small
               'md' : 992,     // medium
               'lg' : 1200     // large
           };
           return sizes[size] ? sizes[size] : 0;
       }
     }

   export default App;
   ```
2. You defined `getResponsiveBreakpoint` as a member of a function so it's lexically scoped inside. That way it's not accessible from the outside. The easiest thing was to convert it to object as I did in code above

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could also make it a static member of a function as such:

```
var App = function () {
    // some logic here  
}

App.getResponsiveBreakpoint: function(size) {
   var sizes = {
       'xs' : 480,     // extra small
       'sm' : 768,     // small
       'md' : 992,     // medium
       'lg' : 1200     // large
    };
    return sizes[size] ? sizes[size] : 0;
}

export default App;
```

I hope that helps for now.